# How to use Complex Queries in iOS CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using `CoreData` in `iOS` to fetch the data from an entity (with relationship). How to fetch data from entity using MAX function which has parent entity relationship ? And also I need to know about DISTINCT Keyword and NOT IN Keyword ?

Example (Same query which is used in SQL Server DB)

1) select max(UNITID) from units where selected date =  07-09-16 and pending =1 and branchid Not In (select * from units where selected date = 07-09-16 and pending == 0)

2) select distinct (branchid) from units  where selected date =  07-09-16

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates

Comment: I think your question as it stands is too broad: take a look at the documentation for NSPredicate and NSExpression.  If you've tried those and are still having problems, post the code you've tried and the particular problems you're having.

Comment: thanks for your reply... i have used NSPredicate  and completed the task....